# Conditional average using linq from qrouped data returns nothing

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, where-clause

I'm calculating average of one field in my data using linq. I want to have my result grouped by two other fields.

```
var Table3 = from d in table1sum.Concat(table2sum)
group d by new { d.Field1, d.Field2 } into dg
    let AverageField3 = dg.Where(g => g.Field3 > 0.0).Average(g => g.Field3)
    let Field4Sum = dg.Sum(g => g.Field4)
    let Field5Sum = dg.Sum(g => g.Field5)
    let Field6Sum = dg.Sum(g => g.Field6)
select new
{
    SupplierID = dg.Key.Field1,
    PropertyID = dg.Key.Field2,
    AverageField3,
    Field4Sum,
    Field5Sum,
    Field6Sum
 };
```

The original data are

```
Table1Sum
    Field1  |Field2 |Field3 |Field4     |Field5 |Field6
    3       |3      |48,00  |3019,00    |603,80 |0,00
    3       |4      |51,00  |3144,00    |628,80 |0,00
    3       |5      |49,00  |3085,00    |617,00 |0,00
    3       |5      |49,00  |3062,00    |612,40 |0,00
    3       |7      |30,00  |42,00      |8,40   |0,00


Table2Sum
    Field1  |Field2 |Field3 |Field4     |Field5 |Field6
    6       |4      |0,00   |0,00       |0,00   |959,80
    4       |7      |0,00   |0,00       |0,00   |529,25
    1       |3      |0,00   |0,00       |0,00   |1730,45
    1       |7      |0,00   |0,00       |0,00   |2127,21
    2       |5      |0,00   |0,00       |0,00   |239,63
    1       |5      |0,00   |0,00       |0,00   |867,23
    6       |3      |0,00   |0,00       |0,00   |501,20
    2       |3      |0,00   |0,00       |0,00   |354,63
    3       |4      |0,00   |0,00       |0,00   |541,54
    3       |3      |0,00   |0,00       |0,00   |683,85
    6       |5      |0,00   |0,00       |0,00   |511,73
    4       |5      |0,00   |0,00       |0,00   |1023,17
```

For some reason I get error "Sequence contains no elements".

What I want is

```
Table3
    Field1  |Field2 |Field3 |Field4     |Field5     |Field6
    3       |3      |48,00  |3019,00    |603,80     |683,85
    3       |4      |51,00  |3144,00    |628,80     |541,54
    3       |5      |49,00  |6147,00    |1229,40    |0,00
    3       |7      |30,00  |42,00      |8,40       |0,00
```

How to change my linq query to obtain correct data?

Edit: Some answers to the questions and comments.

'Field1' has in real live also other values than 3. This just happened to be my test data at this moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like there are groups that don't have any items that satisfy the `Where` condition. The `Average` of an empty sequence of non-nullable values is not zero - it is an exception. For example, there are no items for `Field1` as `6` that have `Field3` greater than zero.

I notice in your "What I want" table you only have the values with `Field1` as `3` - if this represents your real scenario, maybe filter the second table.

A possible fix is to project the values to be nullable:

```
let AverageField3 = dg.Where(g => g.Field3 > 0.0).Average(g => (int?)g.Field3)
```

this will give a `null` value when there aren't any inputs. If you want zero:

```
let AverageField3 = dg.Where(g => g.Field3 > 0.0)
                      .Average(g => (int?)g.Field3)
                      .GetValueOrDefault();
```

(replace the `int?` with `float?` or `decimal?` or whatever it is that matches your data)

Comment: I am curious how using the nullable with average overcomes the sequence issue? I'll probably need to go look at the source.

Comment: Ok found it. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1956 learned something new today, thanks.

Comment: @Nkosi or see the docs; contrast https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358602(v=vs.110).aspx to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338413(v=vs.110).aspx - "The average of the sequence of values, or null if the source sequence is empty or contains only values that are null." vs "The average of the sequence of values." with a documented exception of "InvalidOperationException 
source contains no elements."

Comment: @Nkosi btw; you're better off using the corefx source these days: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Average.cs#L40-L75

Comment: Thanks for the tip. basically had the other link as a quick bookmark to quickly look up api reference source.